# How do announcements work in articles in Stack Overflow for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

The guides are pretty sparse on the topic, just mentioning announcements "Share quarterly updates, weekly metrics, and project plans with an Article."

What I'd like to know is: **do announcements in articles in Teams send everyone in the team a notification?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Announcement" article type is mostly a special tag that groups other articles of that sort. It doesn't create any special notices for the members of the team. While we may add features for this in the future, they're not currently available, and we don't have them planned at this point.

This is tacitly covered in the [Articles page in our Teams Help Center](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4397209-articles-overview):

> Article types give your team members a general idea of the type of content within each article. Next, pick at least one tag to categorize your article. You can add up to five tags.

As it says, this is primarily a sorting feature, not a true announcement that will be shared with others. If you want all of the members of your Team to see it, you'll need to share it with them however you would generally do so.

It looks like you've already poked around at our documentation some, but if you haven't, [the Teams Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/tour) is a good place to start. There's some additional info in the [tour's section about articles](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/tour#articles):

[image: Image from the Team Tour showing the part of the Article creation process that includes a walk-through on how to create an article. Description of text is below.]

You can see the helper text in the image reads:

> Find a category that fits your Article. This helps with searching and signals to those who find the content what exactly it is before clicking into the Article.

I hope these two resources will be helpful for you in understanding how Teams works!