# Is the [articles] meta-tag exclusive for Collectives, while it was first introduced as part of Teams?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta

Meta Stack Overflow has the [articles](/questions/tagged/articles) tag. The current excerpt and wiki are:

> Use this tag for questions regarding Articles that were added with the release of Collectives

> [Collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/collectives/info) adds the ability to create [Articles](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/08/10/stack-overflow-for-teams-articles-content-collaboration-knowledge), longer form content that lives on the collective page.
>
> Articles give Recognized Members the opportunity to provide deeper knowledge and insights through how-to-guides, knowledge articles, or announcements.

However, as the linked blog article mentioned, it was introduced first as a feature in Stack Overflow for Teams, and there are existing questions on MSO asking both about Teams and Articles:

- *[Can articles be trialled before purchasing?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401651/can-articles-be-trialled-before-purchasing)*
- *[How do announcements work in articles in Stack Overflow for Teams?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404275/how-do-announcements-work-in-articles-in-stack-overflow-for-teams)*
- *[Allow viewing articles by their tag in Stack Overflow for Teams](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404934/allow-viewing-articles-by-their-tag-in-stack-overflow-for-teams)*
- *[Are the article types configurable and will there be support for attachments?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406786/are-the-article-types-configurable-and-will-there-be-support-for-attachments)*

So, the discussion point is: should the [articles](/questions/tagged/articles) tag only be used for Collectives, or should its scope also cover Teams?

Comment: Looks like that the articles tag is used only for collectives. However the questions that asking about Articles in Teams use stack-overflow-for-teams tag.

Answer (score 14):

If there are questions about both features this seems like a reasonable discussion to have. I was actually discussing it with JNat yesterday and we decided that the tag seemed to only apply to Collective articles since the tag description explicitly mentions Collectives and there didn't seem to be any questions about Teams articles.

Even if there are actually questions about both I think it's sensible to separate them from each other since the functionality is different between the two and will likely continue to diverge. As such, I'd recommend having two different tags to disambiguate between the two - teams-articles and collectives-articles.

We also use the tags internally to route [status-review](/questions/tagged/status-review) tagged questions to the different development teams. This is something that we could figure out separately if y'all think that one tag for both is better, but I think there's a reasonable argument for two tags.

If that's the preference, I can rename the [articles](/questions/tagged/articles) since all questions already appear to apply to Collective articles and create a new tag for Teams Articles questions.

Comment: It's the same dilemma we routinely confront on the main site... Do we need [[tag:java-string]] and [[tag:c++-string]], or is it sufficient for the language tag to disambiguate the [[tag:string]] tag? Here, it seems that the presence of either (or both of, in certain rare instances) the [[meta-tag:collectives]] or [[meta-tag:stack-overflow-for-teams]] tag would be sufficient to disambiguate the [[meta-tag:articles]] tag.

Comment: "I can rename the articles since all questions already appear to apply to Collective articles and create a new tag for Teams Articles questions" yeah, that would prevent ambiguity. Or, if desired, just rename all articles to collectives. Do the collective team need several tags to follow?

Comment: @Braiam _"just rename all articles to collectives. Do the collective team need several tags to follow?"_ Are you proposing using one tag (i.e., [collectives]) for questions about collectives (including articles)? If so, I disagree. Having the [articles] tag does not just benefit the team. I think it's better to have a tag for articles so we can easily separate them from other collectives questions. I agree with Cody. Let's keep everything as is and edit the tag info of [articles] so that it's not specifically about articles in collectives. An article is an article after all.

Comment: @41686d6564 an article isn't an article in both places. I have a feeling that how the two are used will be vastly different between the two spaces. There's no restrictions on what an Article on a team can contain. I think that's going to be vastly different on the public site.

Comment: @41686d6564 ask the team, instead of going off by your own assumptions. That's what my comment does, asks Catija if the team really needs two tags for the product.

Comment: @Braiam My point was that even if the team does not need two tags, it's still good for the community, IMO, to have a tag for collective articles. Whether one [article] tag is enough and can be shared between both products is another debate. I still lean towards one [article] tag but I don't know how many (technical) differences the two types of articles may have in the future. Of course, staff members know more and Catija seems to believe there will be major differences. CC: Catija.

Comment: @41686d6564 the community would be better served if the team can focus on a single tag. Tags are for the consumers of  the questions, in this case the team. They should decide the best way to do they job, which actually is good for the community.